# Cannot resolve symbol R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material

Tags: android

My code sample -

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_material);
    upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            finish();
        }
    });
```

It was working fine. But today I open the project and it is showing " Cannot resolve symbol 'abc_ic_ab_back_material' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuilding your project might fix the problem, if not
Make sure that you have imported the correct R class, it should be like

```
import <YourPackage>.R;
```

if it is correct, then make sure you have the drawable inside your `drawable` folder. If so then try `File -> Invalidate Cache -> Invalidate and Restart`

Answer (score 0):

Try sync, this could happen when your R file is not imported correctly.